# How to implement dynamic form rendering in Angular using an JSON schema?

Tags: angular

I am working on a project where I have to implement dynamic forms in Angular 6 based on a JSON Schema, So, wanted some suggestions on how to go forward with it.

Answer (score 3):

We use the ngx-formly module for rendering forms using json schema. It is a very vast library with awesome community support and a whole lot of features. You just need to pass your json schema in a specific format and the form will be rendered with all validations.

https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly
GitHub - ngx-formly/ngx-formly: JSON powered / Dynamic forms in ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use some library and build your application you could use **[ng-dynamic-form](https://github.com/udos86/ng-dynamic-forms)** library.

If you want to build on your own use [`reactive forms`](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) with **[`dynamic component loader`](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)**

Comment: I wanted to build it from scratch

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dynamic-form-schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamic-form-schema). dynamic-form-schema provides a base class and a service. Base class can be derived/extend by your Component and you are free to provide your own View (template).

No dependency on an already created dynamic form component - That is an implementation of [Formly](https://formly.dev/) or [ng-dynamic-form library](https://github.com/udos86/ng-dynamic-forms)

Check answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68513528/4424365