# Dynamically create forms from JSON Schema [Angular 8]

Tags: javascript, angular, git, npm

I'm struggling with creating dynamically forms from JSON Schema in Angular 8. I found some libraries for that, but [one is very old](https://github.com/dschnelldavis/angular2-json-schema-form) (last commit ~2 yr ago) and [fork of it](https://github.com/rhalff/angular2-json-schema-form/tree/angular-8) from this year.

I don't want to use first one, because it's deprecated with angular 8, so my choise was the second one. I have trouble because this project isn't on any npm repositories, only on github. I downloaded it form git like this:

```
npm i rhalff/angular2-json-schema-form#angular-8
```

When I started to build my project with this dependency and after attach the import into `app.module.ts` the result is like this:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:20:65 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2-json-schema-form'.
```

I found that in `node_module` there isn't any src or dist folder and then I looked into github projecet and I found that in `/.npmignore` there is a src.

I have a some solution about that, but it's not the final one and I think is really bad idea. 
I will locally clone git repository, next then build it with `npm run build` and then `npm link` 
and then `npm link <someName>` in project catalog.

Can anyone know is there any solution of this problem or maybe someone can suggest me any other libraries for converting JSON Schema for Angular 8 forms?

Comment: If you think you can make it work fork the package in your github then while installing npm run this `npm install --save username/repo#branch-name-or-commit-or-tag` from your github account (make sure it is public for npm to find)after making your desired changes. I mean if you are too desperate to use this. Looks like the author is silent from 2yrs

Comment: I point it out that the first one solution isn't my choise, and in this fork (second one solution) there is a branch called `angular8` and I want to use it from it.

Comment: ok sorry i didn't see that. yup you can fork it again from here and try removing the src from npm ignore see if it works in your own github account

Comment: I found working fork which is continuously support and I have integrate it with success into my project. If someone would be looking for working example, here it is this fork on github: https://github.com/hamzahamidi/Angular6-json-schema-form and on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular6-json-schema-form.

Answer (score 9):

You may consider using [Formly](https://formly.dev/) which support `json-schema` and it provides a bunch of examples to get started https://formly.dev/examples/advanced/json-schema

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. It may not cover some complex scenarios but can do good with less complex forms.

**in form.ts**

```
public form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
public fields = [
  {label: 'Full Name', name: 'full_name', type: 'text'},
  {label: 'Email', name: 'email', type: 'email'},
  {label: 'Comments', name: 'comments', type: 'textarea'},
]

constructForm(){
    let controls = {};
    fields.map(field => {
       controls[field.name] = new FormControl('');
    });
    this.form = new FormGroup(controls);
  }
```

**in form.html**

```
   <form [formGroup]="form">
     <div *ngFor="let field of fields">
       <label for="{{field.name}}">{{field.label}}</label>
       <div [ngSwitch]="field.type">
    
          <!-- textarea -->
          <textarea *ngSwitchCase="'textarea'" [formControlName]="field.name"></textarea>
    
          <!-- other input fields (text, password, number, email) -->
          <input *ngSwitchDefault id="{{field.id}}" type="{{field.type || 'text'}}" [formControlName]="field.name" />
        </div>
     </div>
   </form>
```

This is just a basic structure of how I am doing it. You may add more props to field objects even an "on change" handler function and play more. i.e. css_classes, maxlength, and can do in html like `field.propName`

like:

```
{label: 'Complex Field', name: 'complex_field, type: 'text', onChange: () => {console.log("Something Happened")}}
```

And

```
<input type="{{field.type}} (change)="field.onChange()" [formControlName]="field.name" />
```

Good Luck

Answer (score -1):

You can use [dynamic-form-schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamic-form-schema). It is completely schema based and provide options to add validations, conditional validations and drop down conditional option in the schema.
For more details, check link: [Rapid Angular Reactive Form Component Development Based on a Schema](https://medium.com/@sandhu32/rapid-angular-reactive-form-component-development-based-on-a-schema-73381d4ec54a)